# What is the quickest way to manage Git over a network?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, samba, tortoisegit

I'm a web developer and Subversion/TortoiseSVN user who is looking to jump over to Git as we are starting to need branching and from what I have read, Git is faster and manages branching much better.

**Our SVN Setup**

Our SVN setup is based on a central Linux server accessed through Samba shares. It has Apache, MySQL, PHP, etc. installed, allowing us to test locally on an environment similar to our online live server. We have set up a share which hosts the SVN repositories and development environments (repository checkouts). This allows us to develop in real time, test and view each other's development environments over the local network before committing. So, all checkouts/updates/commits/development are done via a Samba share over a network. No development is done on any other box. We noticed TortoiseSVN/SVN starting to bog down lately and found the branching quite slow. So, we are looking to move to Git.

**Setting up Git**

In an attempt to set up a similar environment to our SVN setup, I have installed Git on the Linux server, installed TortoiseGit on my windows 7 machine. I then proceeded to follow [instructions of cloning an SVN repository to Git](http://jonmaddox.com/2008/03/05/cleanly-migrate-your-subversion-repository-to-a-git-repository/). This has gone well and kept my log intact.

**Setting up a Git Development Environment**

I then created a development environment and did a 'Git Clone' from TortoiseGit which took a few minutes (as I expected). *Do I presume correctly that this is the same as `svn checkout` from TortoiseSvn?* I then made some changes to files and opted for 'Git Comment -> master...'. *Do I presume correctly that this is the same as `svn commit`?* This is where things took a rather long time.

**Where Git Slows Down**

Firstly, it took ages for it to display the files that have changed (around 45 seconds) despite me only changing 2 files. This would normally occur within 2-3 seconds on TortoiseSVN. I then proceeded to commit in which took around another 30 seconds when it probably would have been less than 5 seconds on TortoiseSVN.

Some might ask why I'm moving as the times above for SVN aren't bad. Keep in mind, this is a simple example. Normal usage would make SVN take a lot longer.

**Looking for Solutions**

I did find another person on Stack Overflow with a very similar issue, but there wasn't any actual resolution. Doing things via ssh/commandline isn't an option as a few of the developers aren't very good with that kind of stuff and know nothing about Linux.

So, is there something I can do to make this work faster over the network? Or, perhaps a better alternative to TortoiseSVN to manage the committing, branching, etc.? We are trying to keep the steps we have to take to a minimum to keep things speedy.

Comment: Considered having a look at using git as the frontend for svn for a while?  http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html

Comment: NB: `git commit` is not the equivalent of `svn commit`.  `git commit` commits changes to your local repository but does not send them to the remote server.  `git push` is the command that sends your changes to a remote repository.

Comment: First `git status` on a fresh working copy for a large repo can be quite long, but next ones should be much faster due to some disk caching

Comment: Also, it is not clear whether you're doing git operations on the server's share, or locally cloned on your box?

Comment: I'm doing it on the servers' share.

Comment: I have never seen such slow times with Git. Git was meant to have one repository per project. Did you put the whole svn repository (multiple projects) into one git repo?

Comment: nope, i think it must be slow because the git repo is on a sever and then im cloning it from my computer onto that server into a different folder. So, everything has to go through the network.

Comment: please use @user so that we get notified of your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't expect git to be fast if you have your working copy on a server share. Git is meant to be run locally, and pushed/pulled remotely.